Flutter Error compiling application in flutter VSC
anyone who can help me. I'm new to flutter and dart. I have an app that I'm trying to run and compile, but I have several errors to continue sharing them with if someone has more knowledge and can help me.
enter image description here
enter image description here
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to C:\Users\GESTION GLOBAL DC\Documents\APP\flex\New-Ecommerce-abrar-main\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 34
  ...
}

../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_stripe-7.0.0/lib/src/widgets/card_field.dart:206:37: Error: The getter 'subtitle1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'subtitle1'.
        Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1?.fontSize?.toInt() ??

./../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_stripe-7.0.0/lib/src/widgets/card_field.dart:314:55: Error: The getter 'subtitle1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'. - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart'). Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'subtitle1'. final baseTextStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1; ^^^^^^^^^ ../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_stripe-7.0.0/lib/src/widgets/card_field.dart:327:65: Error: The getter 'errorColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'. 
- 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart'). 
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'errorColor'. 
theme.inputDecorationTheme.errorStyle?.color ?? theme.errorColor,


./../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutterwave_standard-1.0.4/lib/view/payment_widget.dart:61:19: Error: No named parameter with the name 'primary'. 
primary: widget.style.getButtonColor(), ^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/elevated_button.dart:196:22: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match. static ButtonStyle styleFrom({ 
^^^^^^^^^ 
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 
* What went wrong: 
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. 
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1



* Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org 
BUILD FAILED in 22m 53s 
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


change the packages version in pubspec file.
example :
flutter_stripe: 7.0.0 to flutter_stripe :7.0.4
Find all packages that caused errors and update them accordingly
